# Can I edit Finder context menu items with Hammerspoon?

Tags: hammerspoon

With Automator I can [create Quick Actions](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-create-a-new-macos-finder-quick-action-with-automator/) in Finder. Is it possible to do the same thing with Hammerspoon?